# How to build boost with boost_thread_win32-mt-s (crosscompile with mingw)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, mingw

I can't build Boost on Linux for Windows with MinGW (I can't create **boost_thread_win32-mt-s**).

It's a version of OS:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

It's a version of mingw:

```
# i586-mingw32msvc-g++ --version
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ (GCC) 4.2.1-sjlj (mingw32-2)
```

I downloaded Boost version 1.50.
I try to build it:

```
echo "using gcc : 4.2 : i586-mingw32msvc-g++ ;" > user-config.jam
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 --user-config=user-config.jam \
     --with-thread \
     --with-system \
     -sNO_BZIP2=1 \
     -sNO_ZLIB=1 \
     --layout=tagged \
     --build-type=complete \
     link=static,shared \
     runtime-link=static,shared \
     threading=single,multi \
     toolset=gcc \
     target-os=windows \
     address-model=32 \
     release stage
```

After:

```
# pwd
/usr/src/boost_1_50_0/stage/lib
# ls -1
libboost_system-mt-s.a
libboost_system-mt.a
libboost_system-mt.dll
libboost_system-mt.dll.a
libboost_system-s.a
libboost_system.a
libboost_system.dll
libboost_system.dll.a
```

Why I can't build "**boost_thread_win32-mt-s**" or other "**boost_thread*_XXX***"?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I forgot to mention the thread model for Win *(threadapi=win32)*.

Solution:

```
echo "using gcc : 4.2 : i586-mingw32msvc-g++ ;" > user-config.jam
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 --user-config=user-config.jam \
     --with-thread \
     --with-system \
     -sNO_BZIP2=1 \
     -sNO_ZLIB=1 \
     --layout=tagged \
     --build-type=complete \
     link=static,shared \
     runtime-link=static,shared \
     threading=single,multi \
     toolset=gcc \
     target-os=windows \
     threadapi=win32 \
     address-model=32 \
     release stage
```

Thanks!